Given $N = X^2 + Y^2$ find $N = Z^2 + W^2$ where N is a composite number of at least two primes congruent to 1 mod 4 and X,Y are given, but not Z,W
A recent post to the GP-Pari discussion group asked if there was any way to find the second pair of integers Z,W, given that $N = X^2 + Y^2$ where N is a product of two prime numbers $P1, P2$ and both are congruent to 1 mod 4, such that $Z^2 + W^2 = N$. The poster was very careful to NOT give the values of the 2 prime numbers, only $N,X,Y$.
A typical example is $65 = 1^2 + 8^2 = 4^2 + 7^2 = 65 = 5*13$ where 5 and 13 are primes congruent to 1 mod 4.
Solving for Z,W given N,X,Y leads to the equation (1) where
$
(X+a)^2 + (Y+b)^2 = N \tag{1}
$
And using the fact that $X^2 + Y^2 = N$, we can reduce (1) to (2) :
$
a^2 + b^2 + 2(Xa+Yb) = 0 \tag{2}
$
or perhaps more conveniently:
$
a^2 + b^2 = -2(Xa+Yb) \tag{3}
$
It is clear that $a,b$ cannot both be positive, either 1 or the other is negative and the value $Xa+Yb < 0$ or both $a,b$ are negative for (3) to be satisfied. It also has to be noted that both $a,b$ are odd or both $a,b$ are even, they cannot be of opposite parity.
This is simply factoring the number N, given X,Y and trying to find Z,W, and then X,Y,Z,W are made into Gaussian integers: $ A = X + Y\sqrt{-1}$ and $B = Z + W\sqrt{-1}$ and finding the gcd between the real part of the $A*B$ and the imaginary part of $A*B$ which divides $N$.
Any ideas using continued fractions to solve (3) ?

$5=|2+i|$ and $13=|3+2i|,$ so $5\cdot13=|2+i| |3+2i|=|2+i||3-2i|$

Let p & q be a prime Cong to 1 mod 4 then their product always written as sum of two squares in two different ways by using Brahmagupta - Fibonacci Identity

Notably, finding Z,W allows us to factor N via Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity. $P1=\frac{gcd(X+Z,Y+W)^2 + gcd(X-Z,W-Y)^2}{4}$ with the right assignment of Z and W (else swap Z and W).
